# What is the relation between web server like "apache2" and this user www-data?

Tags: networking, server, apache2

What is the relation with this user www-data and web server like apache2?

Comment: perhaps this [answers your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873839/what-is-the-www-data-user)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntun version 20.04.1